# How to completely backup a Linux Image and then load it in another server?

Tags: linux, backup, unix

Complete exact copy!

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/80205/clone-a-working-linux-server/80231

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are wanting exact same partition layout then:

**Open Source**

- [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org)
- [PartImage](http://www.partimage.org)
- [dd/netcat](http://www.rajeevnet.com/hacks_hints/os_clone/os_cloning.html)

**Commercial**

- [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com.au)
- [Norton Ghost](http://www.symantec.com/norton/ghost)

Or if you just want the data then cpio or tar can achieve those results too

**NOTE:** Most of these require physical access. If this is to be done via a hosted solution then you may look at the dd/netcat option and you could substitute dd with cpio or tar.

Comment: +1 For Clonezilla. I've been deploying Ubuntu business networks (desktop and server) with it for a while now. Set up one workstation to have just what you need, configure ldap/pam .. and viola :)

Comment: Acronis works on strange softraid controllers where most rescue distros fail. +1 for Acronis... Worth every cent IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to backup partition schema, but data, **[rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/)** is a great tool.

Answer (score 1):

Take into account that hardware differences might make the copy system unbootable.

Although Linux is more flexible, there might be a situation where the system wont boot.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... I have to throw this in... backing up Linux via imaging is a disaster waiting to happen. What happens when your hardware dies and you need to migrate to something different - different platform, drivers, etc.? What happens when you want to build a duplicate of the machine for testing, but need to change just a few things?

It's a big pain and a lot of work, but I've been handling this issue with existing infrastructure at work, and I'd really recommend going to a combination of file-based backup and automated installation/configuration. You'll get a lot more flexibility in the long run and, though setting it up for existing hosts is a pain, it will save a lot of trouble when the image eventually needs to be installed on different hardware.

Answer (score 0):

**To create image**

> cat /dev/sda | gzip -c > sda.image.gz

**To write imageback**

> sudo sh -c “gunzip -c sda.image.gz | cat > /dev/sda”

Note that /dev/sda is just a generic drive, use "fdisk -l" to find what your drives identifier really is.

Comment: You might want to put that the $CWD is NOT on sda, otherwise you may have a bit of an issue here!

Comment: Can you perform this on a live system (output of course to /dev/sdb)?

Comment: blank3, yes you can, the drive being imaged just should not be mounted at the time.

Answer (score 0):

[Mondo Rescue](http://www.mondorescue.org/) doesn't require physical access. Once saved me from travelling 700km! I just created and downloaded the image, copied it onto a HDD and sent it via mail. Someone just loaded the disk onto slave server and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The "dd" command will clone a partition to a new device.

Answer (score 0):

G4U (Ghost for Unix), NetBSD based live CD

[G4U: Harddisk Image Cloning for PCs](http://www.feyrer.de/g4u/)