# copy Linux server from one box to another

Tags: linux, centos, hardware, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clone a working Linux server](https://serverfault.com/questions/80205/clone-a-working-linux-server)

We have a Linux CentOS server set up to server a php/mysql web application.  We would like to move this to a new larger server.  It appears the best way to do this is to run the CentOS setup on the new machine and then copy over certain configuration and application files.  Is this best approach?

Also, if so,  what directories or files on the new box should not be over-written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install CentOS latest available (5.6) on new server
2. Compile Apache, php, mysql etc [make sure that all modules compiled in old server also in new server]
3. Copy all document root folders and files in same structure.
4. rsync all MySQL files or take dump and restore it in new server. [if your old server have MySQL 4.x then you should install same version of MySQL on new server too.]
5. Recreate Apache configuration files